# How to update DOM from $firebaseArray scope?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, angularfire

How I can update DOM from inside a $firebaseArray?
Currently the DOM not update until after the loop is done.

HTML

```
  <div>{{trip.load_progress}}% Loading</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
   $scope.syncArray = $firebaseArray(ref_read_path);
            $scope.trip = {};
            $scope.trip.load_progress = 1;
            $scope.syncArray.$loaded().then(function(items) {
                    for(var z = 0 ; z < items.length ; z++) {
                        var percentage = Math.round(items.length / 100);
                        if (z == percentage * $scope.trip.load_progress) {
                                $scope.trip.load_progress = $scope.trip.load_progress  + 1;
                        }
                    }
            })
```

The same when I use:
ref_read_path.once("value", function (tripPath) { ...} of Firebase

Answer (score 1):

By implementing `$loaded()` your code runs at a moment when Angular isn't aware of it anymore. To make Angular pick up your changes to the scope, run the code in the digest cycle by using `$timeout()`:

```
$scope.syncArray = $firebaseArray(ref_read_path);
$scope.trip = {};
$scope.trip.load_progress = 1;
$scope.syncArray.$loaded().then(function(items) { 
    $timeout(function() {
        for(var z = 0 ; z < items.length ; z++) {
            var percentage = Math.round(items.length / 100);
            if (z == percentage * $scope.trip.load_progress) {
                    $scope.trip.load_progress = $scope.trip.load_progress  + 1;
            }
        }
    });
})
```